# How can I repeat the same node in javascript to edit html?

Tags: javascript, python, html, nodes, appendchild

I have a html/javascript based program which I am using in python flask. The real problem is with my javascript code.

```
@app.route('/')
def server():
    def server_generator():
        yield(render_template("layout.html"))
        text = request.args.get('text')
        if text != None:
            yield("""
            <script>
                var maindiv = document.createElement('div');
                maindiv.setAttribute('class', 'container');
                var mainp = document.createElement('p');
                mainp.setAttribute('class', 'user');
                var mainspan = document.createElement('span');
                mainspan.setAttribute('class', 'time-right');
                var text = document.createTextNode("{0}");
                var time = document.createTextNode("{1}");
                mainp.appendChild(text);
                mainspan.appendChild(time);
                maindiv.appendChild(mainp);
                maindiv.appendChild(mainspan);
                bossdiv = document.getElementById('serverid');
                bossdiv.appendChild(maindiv);
            </script>
            """.format(data, server_info))
    return Response(stream_with_context(server_generator()))
```

The code above works once, but after the second time, it just writes over the first appended node. I tried using `.cloneNode(true)`, but it didn't work (or I didn't use it properly). I'm not sure how to resolve this type of issue and what I need to add to append the same node multiple times.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the function is called multiple times.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok, I edited my question. Keep in mind it is a flask app, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't look like `maindiv` is actually appended to the document at the moment - is there code that does that elsewhere in the script?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm sorry, I forgot to add the code that I used before I troubleshooted myself. This should be the pre-troubleshooted code.

Comment: I don't know Flask, but I can't reproduce the problem with the `<script>`: https://jsfiddle.net/ex4nt2fj/